# How to use Composer to autoload Phalcon classes?

Tags: php, composer-php, phalcon

I'm trying to use Phalcon (it works as an extension but I want to use via source code). The source is downloaded, of course when I try to run, it fails, it won't find certain classes. It's at the very index.php, so I can't find the way to autoload those classes. But I have a Composer, how to say "Hey, load Phalcon directory from here?" I'm noob at composer.

Comment: You want use composer to download Phalcon or use autoloading to load already existing classes?

Comment: autoloading already existing classes

Comment: Phalcon is written in Zephir and compiled to a PHP extension. Unless you are compiling it yourself you cannot use it from source code. Without it being compiled the Phalcon classes won't exist in PHP.

Comment: You have to compile the source and then install the resulting extension (copy it to the right place and edit your server config file). It is not written in PHP, it creates a PHP extension meaning the classes are already in memory (hence the massive speed increase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To autoload PHP classes you must use `spl_autoload_register()` and (optionally if not using namespaces) PSR-2 directory structure/naming (where each namespace segment means folder in system).

```
[autoload.php]

spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    $namespace = str_replace("\\","/",__NAMESPACE__);
    $namespace = empty($namespace) ? "" : $namespace."/";
    $className = str_replace("\\","/",$className);
    $class = CORE_PATH."/classes/{$namespace}{$className}.php";
    include_once($class);
});
```

---

```
[index.php]

include_once('/path/to/autoload.php');

$myClass = new MyNameSpace\MyClass();
```

---

```
[file system]

root
  |
   \-MyNameSpace
    |
    |-MyClass.php
    |-OtherClass.php
  |
   \-Namespace2
    |
    //other classes.
```

As you can see there is no use of composer. Composer is intended for downloading some packages and after that he will generate autoloading file for you.